# Php-soap client installation in Joomla

Tags: soap, joomla1.5

What is the process of installing Php-soap client in Joomla. I didn't find any package about php-soap client.

When I run my sample it throw the error message : Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /hermes/bosweb/web088/b886/ywh.brett/stratalliance/components/com_jumi/jumi.php(25) : eval()'d code on line 3

Please somebody help me, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you probably haven't enabled soap on your php installation
if you're not on your own managed host, you're probably out of luck, contact your hosting provider and ask them if they can enable it for you